# Inputting commas in spaces (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show commas on my number display

currently only "22" is displaying, however there is another 6 digits and 2 commas missing..... "22,523,241" is the full number and how it appears on the HTML. I've written the following script:

The page can be viewed here : https://volocommerce.com - you will see the problem halfway down, the numbers just stick and don't show anything after the comma.... I'd love to get this sorted, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Just to add:-

The entire HTML/javascript is like this right now (using custom fields from Wordpress)

```
    <script src="/....../js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script>
      $.fn.waypoint.defaults = {
  context: window,
  continuous: false,
  enabled: true,
  horizontal: false,
  offset: 0,
  triggerOnce: true
}

    $('.facts_waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {  
    function count($this){
        var current = parseInt($this.html().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);
        if (current >= 1000000) {current = current +493023;}
        else if (current >= 10000) {current = current +43749;}
        else if (current >= 1000) { current = current + 7369;}
        else { if (current >= 100) { current = current + 197;}
                else {current = current + 1}
        }
        /*current = current + 100;  Where 1 is increment */

        $this.html(++current);
        if(current > $this.data('count')){
            $this.html($this.data('count'));
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
        }
    }
    jQuery(".count_one, .count_two, .count_three").each(function() {
      jQuery(this).data('count', parseInt(jQuery(this).html(), 10));
      jQuery(this).html('0');
      count(jQuery(this));
    });
});

</script>

<div class="home_stats">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 padtop40 center">
                <h2 class="green_txt title font50 mar0">
                <?php if(get_field('stats_title')) { echo get_field('stats_title'); }?>
                </h2>
                <div class="grey_txt font20 marbot20">
                <?php if(get_field('stats_subtitle')) { echo get_field('stats_subtitle'); }?>
                </div>

                <div class="row padtop40 font12">
                <div class="col-md-4 marbot40">
                  <div class="grey_txt">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_1_title')) { echo get_field('stat_1_title'); }?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="count_one orange_txt title font46">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_1_number')) { echo get_field('stat_1_number'); }?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 marbot40">
                  <div class="grey_txt">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_2_title')) { echo get_field('stat_2_title'); }?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="count_one orange_txt title font46">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_2_number')) { echo get_field('stat_2_number'); }?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 marbot40">
                  <div class="grey_txt">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_3_title')) { echo get_field('stat_3_title'); }?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="count_one orange_txt title font46">
                  <?php if(get_field('stat_3_number')) { echo get_field('stat_3_number'); }?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to show a comma in the correct places, but I've tried using LocaleNumber - this didn't work and only caused an increasing number.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: after I reloaded the page I saw the complete number.. some kind of race condition?

Comment: if you reload the page on the numbers are fixed :) - intended behaviour. Start @ top and go down.

Comment: You do realize that parseInt('22,523,241', 10); will only return 22, right? The commas are not part of an "int". The number with the commas is just a representation of the value -- the commas should not be part of the int being parsed. You  can format the display of the RESULTING parseInt with commas, but parseInt will ignore the commas.

Comment: One number has comma's  - the other does not... Neither show commas on the page

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the line:

```
jQuery(this).data('count', parseInt(jQuery(this).html(), 10));
```

With this:

```
jQuery(this).data('count', parseInt(jQuery(this).html().trim().replace(/,/g, ""),10));
```

Edit: to save the number
`var num = parseInt(jQuery(this).html().trim().replace(/,/g, ""),10);`
if you want to have the commas: `num.toLocaleString("en-US");`
decide how you want to save it

```
jQuery(this).data('count', num);
jQuery(this).data('count', num.toLocaleString("en-US"));
```

Comment: that removed the commas and displayed the full number - thanks for that :) But I'd love to SHOW the comma too, is this possible?

Comment: this works with the commas being inserted, but stops the entire animation :(   -  thank you anyway, it is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In other words, numbers and string are two, different types. Numbers have to be a certain way, in code: without commas. Enjoy your day, man!